# Electron interference and light interference

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, interference

In the double slit experiment, I see that shooting electrons one by one, with a time interval between them, eventually creates a pattern that resembles that of light interference. But, before the passage of a long time and many electrons, I only see electrons at different places. So, if they say that the electron has a dual property, and light has a dual property, how can light exhibit that same shape - not pattern really - before that long time? I mean, the pattern produced by shooting electrons one by one, does that resemble the pattern formed by light? Imagine that we shoot photon by photon, will the same thing happen?

Comment: A relevant question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/76162/26076

Answer (score 1):

In the one-photon experiment you should see them. The problem is that it is very difficult to build a [single-photon source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-photon_source) and to make such an experiment.

Comment: See also my description of one photon sources [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/76268/26076)

Comment: Indeed, that is relevant to the question