# How can i only shine/shoot one proton/electron per second?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, double-slit-experiment, protons

I would like to test out the two slit experiment but only one electron or proton at a time.

This question is different from the rest that people are saying are duplicates as I am clearly asking how can "I" shine/shoot one proton/electron per second? The answer clearly explains how I can do this. I am not tring to understand how it works, or see experiments, im asking how it is possible for "me" to do it. As you can see from my accepted answer.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/76162/

Comment: Before you invest a lot of time in getting the rate down, hove you shown that you can do diffractive scattering with particle beams at all? Getting the basic set-up working is a non-trivial project compared to reducing the rate. No point in putting a lot of energy into a super special source if you can't run the experiment at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets run a few numbers.  Go with electrons. 200keV electrons (like from a standard transmission electron microscope). These have a velocity of just about 2E8 m/sec (yes, relativistic effects need to be taken into account). One nano-ampere is a little more than 6E9 electrons per second. Dividing through, that gives you, on average, 30 electrons per meter of path length, or one every 3ish centimeters.  Pass it through an electron-transparent material, say 100nm thick. That is 1E-5cm, or an average of 3E-6 electrons in the sample at any given time. And you get a beautiful diffraction pattern quite easily.

So, every single TEM-generated diffraction pattern you have ever seen has been generated with way less than 1 electron in the sample at any point in time...