# What is the particle physics level description of corresponding optical diffraction of light?

Tags: optics, particle-physics, diffraction

At the particle physics level, what is responsible for the so called diffraction of light in optics thematic of general macroscopic physics ?

Comment: I'm unclear what you are really asking.

Comment: I ask for the explanation in terms of particle physics of the non particle physics of optical diffraction.

Comment: this may help: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/90646/what-is-the-relation-between-electromagnetic-wave-and-photon/90672#90672

Comment: I think that my answer to a similar question here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/285142/shooting-a-single-photon/285151#285151 , answers it.

Comment: I was expected that answers may mention Pomeron, Regge theory, etc... ?